# Scripting rTorrent

Tags: php, xml-rpc, bittorrent, libtorrent

Documentation on rTorrent is very short, so I'm looking for some references on scripting rTorrent using its own scripting system.

**Concurrent Problem:**
  I need to pass a string through rTorrent.

I want to pass some string to rTorrent (title) and dot torrent link, and after download is complete rTorrent run a php script with torrent's directory name (d.get_name) and the string that I've passed.

This would solve the problem but the string (title) is unique per download:
`system.method.set_key = event.download.finished, handler, "execute= php /php/location $d.get_name 'the title string'"`

P.S: would someone add rTorrent tag to this question?

Comment: If I'm unclear or it is possible to ask better, let me know please.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is very limited indeed. Some things that you need though is a `,` in the execute statement, it will be replaced with a space when it is passed to the shell and to get the path to the torrent you need to do `<$d.get_base_path=>`. So your execute statement will be `execute=php,/php/location/,$d.get_base_path` and not sure how to do the last part where you give 'the title string' to the shell. Would suggest that you do everything that you can do in the script.